# what this command do ? ls /usr/bin | grep ”man” | sed ”s/man/###/”?

Tags: command-line, sed

I have a question
I want to know what this command do

```
ls /usr/bin | grep ”man” | sed ”s/man/###/”
```

I have use this command and show me everything with ###, but I dont know whats mean. 
I hope someone can explain it.

Comment: just out of curiosity, why do you want to execute that command? it seems utterly useless. and if you don't know what it means, why are you trying to execute it? are you just surfing around the internet and executing random commands that you find? ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ls /usr/bin

- list the contents of /usr/bin and only show filenames.

> | grep ”man”

- scan the output of the 1st part and search for "man". Result:

  ```
  ls /usr/bin | grep man
  catman
  dbmmanage
  dh_installman
  dh_installmanpages
  man
  mandb
  manpath
  mysqltestmanager
  mysqltestmanagerc
  mysqltestmanager-pwgen
  pod2man
  w3mman
  ```

> | sed ”s/man/###/”?

- match pattern "man" and change it with "###". But this technically does nothing but echo the result. Example:

  ```
  $ cp /usr/bin/w3mman . 
  $ ls |grep man 
  w3mman 
  $ ls |grep man|sed "s/man/###/" 
  w3m### 
  $wdamen@pluto:~$ ls w3* 
  w3mman
  ```

  The file is still there and there is no file with "###"